# Is $f(x,y) = \frac{x \sin(y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$ with $f(0,0) =0$ continuous?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

I want to know whether the following function is continuous or not, but I have no idea how to do this.

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{x \sin(y^2)}{x^2+y^2}, &\text{if }(x,y)\neq (0,0)\\
0, &\text{if }(x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Note that $|f(x,y)-f(0,0)|\leq |y|/2$.

EDIT. (analytic proof) Function $f$ is defined on and around $(0,0),$ so continuity at $(0,0)$ means $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}f(x,y)=f(0,0)=0$ (either  by definition, either by characterization, depending on the context). Since:

$$|f(x,y)-f(0,0)|\leq  \frac{|x|}{x^2+y^2}y^2=\frac{|xy|}{x^2+y^2}|y|\leq \frac{|y|}{2}$$
and $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}|y|=0$, you get that $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}f(x,y)=f(0,0)=0$, by the squeeze theorem. (note that $|\sin x|\leq |x|,~x\in \mathbb{R}$).

Comment: Thank you for answering! But I don't really see how to prove continuity from this.

Comment: And I also do not indersta nd why this inequality holds.

Comment: @RubenVanBelle To see why the inequality is true recall that $\forall x,y,t\in \mathbb R\left(|xy|\leq \dfrac{x^2+y^2}{2}\land |\sin(t)|\leq |t|\right)$.

Comment: @Nikolaos If you're not going to suggest an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof, why focus on $\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\left(|f(x,y)-f(0,0)|\right)$ instead of  $\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\left(f(x,y)\right)$?

Comment: @GitGud thanks for noting. My aim is to work with the squeeze theorem, that is why I focus on  the difference $|f(x,y)-f(0,0)|$. Ιf I were to use the algebra of the limits instead (not applicable here though) I would focus on the limit of $f(x,y)$, straighforward, as you propose. Finally, it all lead to the same thing of course.

Comment: Hmmm... $$|f(x,y)|\leqslant|x|$$